# Horizontal Line in Python Plotly Scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm looking for a way to draw two horizontal lines in a Plotly Scatter plot. My x-axis index is not fixed and keep changing everytime. So I'm looking for a Horizontal line at y = 5 and y = 18 passing horizontally across the chart

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093169/horizontal-vertical-line-in-plotly) for a solution but I'm not sure how to use layouts with Plotly express

My code for scatter plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,6,8,10,12,15,18], "y":[0, 1, 4, 9, 16,13,14,18,19,5,12]})
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y")
fig
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `fig.update_layout()`, here is how:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({ "x":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,6,8,10,12,15,18],
                    "y":[0, 1, 4, 9, 16,13,14,18,19,5,12]})
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y")

# add two horizontal lines
fig.update_layout(shapes=[
    # adds line at y=5
    dict(
      type= 'line',
      xref= 'paper', x0= 0, x1= 1,
      yref= 'y', y0= 5, y1= 5,
    ),
    # adds line at y=18
    dict(
      type= 'line',
      xref= 'paper', x0= 0, x1= 1,
      yref= 'y', y0= 18, y1= 18,
    )
])

fig.show()
```

Which produces this graph:
[image]

I don't know if there is an easier way, but this is what I would use

Answer (score 3):

These days it is simpler using vline (for a vertical line) or hline (for a horizontal line):

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,6,8,10,12,15,18], "y":[0, 1, 4, 9, 
16,13,14,18,19,5,12]})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y")
fig.add_hline(y=5)
fig.add_hline(y=18)

fig.show()
```